# How to know the frame id

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.04, fuerte and Rviz

I would like to visualize the data generated by the /odom topic by gps_common package
and
the data from the laser range finder.

So I would like to know how the frome ID can be found out in general?

Thanks,
Sai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42632/how-to-know-the-frame-id/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2012-08-29

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-08-30**:
There is no output after rostopic echo /odom...Any other way to find the frame ID?

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2012-08-30**:
if there's no output for echo /odom, you will not be able to visualize any data. I suggest you echo the /fix topic instead

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-09-02**:
When the /odom topic started to publish the data i.e. when it got the right data from GPS, then   rostopic echo /odom  gave the frame_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rostopic echo /odom

EDIT:
In general, the frame_id in the header of any topic (if it has a header) can be found by `rostopic echo`. For example, laser scans usually publish on `/scan` topic. So `rostopic echo /scan` will show you what is in frame_id. (You can use `rostopic echo /scan |grep frame_id` to show only that line with the id.

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Frames are published on the `tf` topic. To see all frames and the nodes publishing frames, execute:

```
rosrun tf tf_monitor
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) on 2012-08-30**:
To view the connectiong between frames, you could use "rosrun tf view_frames" which generate a pdf file with  connections graph.

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2012-08-30**:
My understanding of his question is that he's looking for the frame_id in the header of the topic /odom. The gps_common package http://www.ros.org/wiki/gps_common does not broadcast any tf, so will not show up on tf_monitor

**Comment by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) on 2012-08-30**:
You're right